# Why dont show button center of screen android?

Tags: android

I'm beginner in android,and want to write xml file show two button center of screen horizontally,write this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/allow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/TextView01"
        android:text="Allow"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deny"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/allow"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/allow"
        android:text="Deny"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

that show me this:
[image]

but i want this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It will give desired layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/TextView01" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/allow"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Allow" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deny"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Deny" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/allow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Allow"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/deny"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/allow"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/allow"
    android:text="Deny"/>
```

Comment: but not show center of screen,show center of first line

Comment: @user3671271 Edited my answer. Try again plz

Answer (score 0):

First try changing your RelativeLayout height to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.
After that you could put both buttons in a LinearLayout like this:

> ```
>    <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     android:layout_centerInParent="true">
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/allow"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Allow" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/deny"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Deny" />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text or @string reference from strings.xml" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/allow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Allow" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deny"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Deny" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```